# Email field is empty on PhpMail

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple form which sending an email with some fields and also it saves the fields in .csv file.

Here is my code (HTML, jQuery, PHP)

**The Form:**

```
<form id="request-size">
     <input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="cmesgmail" placeholder="email">
     <input type="hidden" name="size" id="size" value="52">
     <input type="hidden" name="sku" id="sku" value="315">
     <input type="hidden" name="pridpr" id="pridpr" value="849">
   <input class="request-size-btn btn" value="SEND">
</form>
```

**The jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.request-size-btn').live('click', function() {
   jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "https://example.com/sendmail.php",
     data: jQuery('form#request-size').serializeArray(),
       success: function( data ) {
          jQuery('.cmesg').empty();
          jQuery('.cmesg').append(data);
       }
      });
   });
});
```

**The PHP Sendmail:**

```
$EmailFrom = $_REQUEST['email'];
$SKU = $_REQUEST['sku'];
$SIZE = $_REQUEST['size'];
$ID = $_REQUEST['pridpr'];
$EmailTo = "info@example.com";
$Subject = "Contact for Size";
$DATENOW = date('d/m/Y h:i:s a', time());

$Body = "";
$Body .= "<b>Email:</b> ";
$Body .= $EmailFrom . "\r\n";
$Body .= "<br>";
$Body .= "<b>Product SKU:</b> ";
$Body .= $SKU . "\n";
$Body .= "<br>";
$Body .= "<b>Product ID:</b> ";
$Body .= $ID . "\n";
$Body .= "<br>";
$Body .= "<b>Product Size:</b> ";
$Body .= $SIZE;
$Body .= "<br>";
$Body .= "<b>Date:</b> ";
$Body .= $DATENOW;

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\n";
$headers .= "From: ". $EmailFrom ."" . "\n";

$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, $headers);

if ($success){
    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">Done!</div>';
    $file = fopen('request-size.csv', 'a');

    $data = array(
        array($EmailFrom, $SKU, $ID, $SIZE, $DATENOW)
    );

    foreach ($data as $row)
    {
        fputcsv($file, $row);
    }

    fclose($file);
}
else{
  echo '<div class="alert alert-danger">Error!</div>';
}
```

I've got all the fields in my csv file and email, except the "email" field. It's always empty. I have also try to change the name of email field (email to emailreq) on both sides (html, php), but didn't work.

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: I've almost never seen the use of `$_REQUEST`. Have you tried `$_POST`?

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, @chade_

Comment: @chade_ yes, nothing happend

Comment: can you please post the output if you try to log the jQuery('form#request-size').serializeArray() to the console (just before doing the request). I suspect the email field is not sent to the server at all...

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? some older versions did not include input fields with type="email"

Comment: @flynorc its 1.4.1

Answer (score 0):

If updating jQuery is an option for you, do that. Version 1.6.2 and up should be working (possibly also before, but i'm not sure).

Otherwise change the

```
<input name="email" id="email" type="email" class="cmesgmail" placeholder="email">
```

to

```
<input name="email" id="email" type="text" class="cmesgmail" placeholder="email">
```

Older versions of jQuery did not include support for the HTML5 input types.